# Array_Filter remove

Tags: php

I also have a problem with the array_filtrer function, more specifically I have an array of free spaces, ex:

```php
Array (
    [0] => "val1"
    [1] => 
    [2] => "val2"
    [3] => 
    );
```

When I use the array_filtrer function, it only removes my last key (in the example above, 3) the middle keys remaining there (as in the example above, the key 1), it can create a solution for it so that removes any key with that null space?

I got the array from a .txt file after I rewrote some parts of it, and at the end of the day I ran into such a problem.

Comment: How are you calling array_filter? Are you including a callback, if not, there may be an issue with the falsiness of your empty values.

Comment: which php version are u using?

Comment: Please include how you read the file as you will probably find that your elements have something like a line feed or new line in them.

Comment: You don't actually show any PHP code. `array_filter()` will indeed remove all falsy values, not just the one at position `[3]`, as you think.

Comment: Are you `trim`ing the lines when read from the file to remove the newline syntax? and more over are you not check if the lilne value is null/empty before adding it to the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$entry = [
    0 => 'val1',
    1 => false,
    2 => "val1",
    3 => null,
    4 => '',
    5 => '0',
    6 => 0,
    7 => '',
];
print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

output

> Array ( [0] => val1 [2] => val1 )